# How to round top and bottom corner of stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I am using c3 js chart libray on a Angular 6 project. Could anyone suggest me a proper solution for that ?
[image]

Comment: I'd look into using a clip-path on the whole stacked bar with rounded ractangle shape

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino can you give a sample or example code? 
Thanks

You can try here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3-rounded-stackedbar?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i don't know how C3 library work, but now I am well known.

> C3 build rectangle chart by using path so it's no point using 
>   `d3.selectAll( 'rect')`

You must edit it by using  :  `d3.selectAll('path')`

Follow this to understand or just copy paste this code below your initialize c3 chart code

Any way your [dummy sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3-rounded-stackedbar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). the d3 library is not working on my side i change
`import d3 from d3` to

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

You initialize c3 chart by using this

```
 chart.bindto = '#chart';
```

> YOURS CHART IS DRAWING

Then add this to make the rounded top corner, this only working when chart already drawing read the explanation

```
 // Select all path on the svg
 d3.selectAll('path').each(function(){
   var x = chart.internal.x //To get xScale on c3
   var height = chart.internal.height // to get chart height on c3
   var data= d3.select(this).data()[0] // to get data on element path d3
   var y =  chart.internal.y // to get Yscale
   var path = d3.select(this).attr('d') // to get attribute d path
   var pathArray =  path.split('L')// to make custumisation
   var rx = 7 // just to set rounded x
   var ry = 7 // just to set rounded y


   // see this it for void any path you dont want to be rounded
   // i see yours first img make sure to change this
   if (data.x === undefined) return 
   if (data.id == 'data2') return

   // after you void any path you dont want to be rounded now its the time 
   d3.select(this).attr('d', function(d,i){
     // get coordinate to be manupulated
     var bwidth1 = pathArray[0].split(',')
     var bwidth2 = pathArray[1].split(',')
     var bwidth3 = pathArray[2].split(',')

     // manipulate coordinate so it can be rounded pretty
     pathArray[1] =bwidth2.map(function(d,i){
       if (i == 1){
         var a = (d*1)+ rx
       } else {
         var a = (d*1)
       }
       return a
     })

    pathArray[2] =bwidth3.map(function(d,i){
      if (i == 1){
         var a = (d*1)
       } else {
         var a = (d*1)-rx
       }
       return a
     })

     // this code make rounded (on $a)
     var a = `
     ${pathArray[0]}


     L${pathArray[1]}

     a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${-ry}
    L${pathArray[2]}

     a${-rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${ry}
     L${pathArray[3]}
     `
     return a

   })
 })
```

Now you can make the top-rounded.

See yours img

For bottom-rounded, i don't know how you draw it, you invert the chart or what.
anyway you did not include it on your dummy code, so i don't make it

> NOTE: when it resize it back to normal, maybe you must add this to
>   the function then call it whenever your chart is changing

Comment: If you need to add the rounded corners to the bottom how would you do it, do you have the sample code for that?

Comment: @JayampathyWijesena see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3-rounded-stackedbar-xgp9ps

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
d3.selectAll("rect")       // select all rectangle
    .attr("rx", 10)         // set the x corner curve radius
    .attr("ry", 10);        // set the y corner curve radius
```

i don't know in c3 if there is another function can be called, but if there is not, just make one

Comment: this will round inner boundaries too, and the chart will look like a stack of ice-cream scoops

Comment: Here you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c3-rounded-stackedbar?file=src/app/app.component.ts